# Bounds on imaginary parts of partial Kloosterman sums?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

For a prime $p$ and integers $a,m$, $0<a,m<p$ define the (partial Kloosterman) sum
$$ S_p(a,m) = \sum_{0<k<m} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}}{p}(a x +  x^{-1})\right), $$
where $x^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $x$ modulo $p$. I know $\Im S_p(a,p)=0$ and that there is the Weil bound
$$ |\Re S_p(a,p)| \leq 2\sqrt{p}. $$

Is there a similar bound on $\Im S_p(a,m)$ that holds for all $m=1,\ldots,p$? I imagine this question might have a known answer in the literature, but I couldn't find anything. Conjectured bounds would also be interesting to me.

A related question: is the Weil bound true for partial sums as well, i.e., is it true that
$$\max_m |\Re S_p(a,m)|\leq 2\sqrt{p}? $$

If I pretend that $(x+a x^{-1})/p$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, then the distribution of real and imaginary parts of each term is the same, but all imaginary terms cancel. So intuitively only half as many imaginary terms contribute to $\max_m |\Im S_p(a,m)|$ as there are real terms that altogether contribute to make up $2\sqrt{p}$. So I would expect some bound of the form
$$ \max_m |\Im S_p(a,m)| \leq 2\sqrt{p/2}, $$
but I am not really convinced this is right (for example: should it be $2\sqrt{p/2}$ because $p$ is halved or $\sqrt{p}$ because the number of terms is halved but $p$ is the same?).

Comment: It's certainly $O(p^{1/2 + o(1)})$ by the usual trick of writing the characteristic function of $[0,m]$ as a linear combination of complex exponentials.  I suspect the imaginary part of a partial sum is not quite $O(p^{1/2})$ as you hope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The partial sums, normalized by $\sqrt{p}$, are unbounded, as one varies $a$ over all invertible classes modulo $p$n and lets $p$ go to infinity.  This follows from results in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7892), which also has more precise information on the distribution of the partial sums, including real and imaginary parts.

(By the way, it is more usual to write $ax+x^{-1}$ in the phase of the Kloosterman sum, instead of $x+ax^{-1}$; this emphasizes that it is, as a function of $a$, the discrete Fourier transform of $e_p(x^{-1})$).

Comment: If I computed right, the first case of 
$\left|{\rm Im} \, S_p(a,m)\right| > \sqrt p$
is ${\rm Im} \, S_{53}(24,14) = 7.2877\ldots = 1.0010\ldots \sqrt{53}$,
and there is no case of  $\left|{\rm Im} \, S_p(a,m)\right| > \sqrt{2p}$ 
for $p<2000$, though the ratios are inching closer to $\sqrt 2$,
and are bound to exceed $\sqrt 2$ eventually.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies One could extract from the methods of the paper you could get an explicif lower bound on an explicit lower bound for the first p where it gets larger than a given constant so you could see when it happens.

Comment: Yes, but I expect that this bound would greatly overestimate the actual first occurrence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link; I managed to plot them [here](http://imgur.com/a/tjn4R).